# Class member function vs function with respect to speed

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Virtual Functions and Performance C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871954/virtual-functions-and-performance-c)

Is this correct, that class member function takes more time than a simple function? What if inheritance and virtual functions are used?

I have tried to collect my functions into a simple interface class (only member functions, no data members), and it appears that I lose time. **Is there a way to fix it?**

P.S. I'm checking  with gcc and icc compilers and using -O3 option.

Comment: Have you profiled code with max optimization level?

Comment: No. I use a simple linux timer.   struct timeval tp;
  gettimeofday(&tp, 0);
  return tp.tv_sec + (tp.tv_usec)*1.e-6;

Comment: If you want an answer to the question of why something is slower, post two pieces of code, one faster and one slower, and hopefully someone will know. Asking us to validate if one of your guesses as to the problem is correct absent any code is fruitless. The question, as stated, is interesting, but not necessarily relevant to your real question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Premature optimization is the root of all evil

A nonstatic member function takes an additional argument, which is the object (a pointer or reference to it) on which the function is called. This is one overhead. If the function is virtual, then there is also one small indirection in case of a polymorphic call, that is, addition of the function index to the virtual table base offset. Both of these "overheads" are sooo negligable, you shouldn't worry about it unless the profiler says this is your bottleneck. Which it most likely is not.

### Premature optimization is the root of all evil

Comment: Optimizer will take care of that.

Comment: A polymorphic function call yields an indirection, not the virtuality of the function per se.

Comment: @phresnel: Note taken, edited

Comment: Upvoted. As far as I know, the standard does not mandate that non-polymorphic calls are implemented non-polymorphically, but g++ 4.x at least shows no indirection in such case.

Comment: @phresnel: the standard doesn't talk about performance at all... so we are naturally talking about existing implementations

Answer (score 5):

Member functions, if they're not virtual, are same as free functions. There is no overhead in its invocation.

However, in case of `virtual` member functions, there is overhead, as it involves *indirection*, and even then, it is slower when you call the virtual function through *pointer* or *reference* (that is called *polymorphic* call). Otherwise, there is no difference if the call is not *polymorphic*.

Comment: In case of polymorphic calls that is. On a value type, g++ shows me no difference and no overhead.

Comment: @phresnel: Did I differ from that?

Comment: Oops, brainfart on my side, sorry.

Comment: @phresnel: I made my post more explicit. I hope it is very clear now.

Answer (score 3):

There is no additional time penalty involved for member functions. Virtual functions are slightly slower but not by much. Unless you're running an incredibly tight loop, even virtual function overhead is negligible.

Comment: A virtual function is not slower, a polymorphic function call is.

Answer (score 2):

For normal functions it's enough with a "jump" to them, which is very fast. The same goes for normal member functions. Virtual functions on the other hand, the address to jump to has to be fetched from a table, which of course involves more machine code instructions and therefore will be slower. However, the difference is negligible and will hardly even be measurable.

In other words, don't worry about it. If you have slowdowns, then it's most likely (like 99,999%) something else. Use a profiler to find out where.